# Solution of an integral equation

Tags: calculus, integral-equations

Consider a simple Wiener-Hopf integral equation of the first kind with unknown function $\phi(x)$ for $x\geq 0$:

$$f(x)=\int_0^\infty \phi(y)\min\{x,y\}\,\mathrm{d}y$$

where $f(x)=x-a$ and $a \geq 0$.

Although it arose from a well stated physical problem, I suggest there are no solutions of any of these equations in $\phi(x)$. Or are they?

Note: Would there be a solution if we choose $f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 &;x<a\\
x-a &;x\geq a
\end{cases}
$ instead?

Comment: Function should be $$f(y)=\int_0^\infty \phi(y)\min\{x,y\}\,\mathrm{d}x$$.

Comment: - It was a mistake in differentials, I will correct that

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> I'll assume the equation is
>   $\ds{\,\mathrm{f}\pars{x} =
> \int_{0}^{\infty}\phi\pars{y}\min\braces{x,y}\,\dd y}$.

\begin{align}
\,\mathrm{f}\pars{x} & =
\int_{0}^{x}\phi\pars{y}y\,\dd y + x\int_{x}^{\infty}\phi\pars{y}\,\dd y
\\[3mm] \imp\
\,\mathrm{f}'\pars{x} & =
\phi\pars{x}x + \int_{x}^{\infty}\phi\pars{y}\,\dd y -
x\phi\pars{x}
\\[3mm] \imp\
\,\mathrm{f}''\pars{x} & =
-\phi\pars{x}\quad\imp\quad\color{#f00}{\phi\pars{x}} =
\color{#f00}{-\,\mathrm{f}''\pars{x} = -\delta\pars{x - a}}
\end{align}

---

$$\mbox{because}\
\mathrm{f}\pars{x} = \Theta\pars{x - a}\pars{x - a}\ \imp\
\mathrm{f}'\pars{x} = \Theta\pars{x - a}\ \imp\
\mathrm{f}''\pars{x} = \delta\pars{x - a}
$$

> Checking ?:
>   $$
> \int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{-\delta\pars{y - a}}\min\braces{x,y}\,\dd y =
> -\min\pars{x,a} =
> \left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
> \ds{-x} & \mbox{if} & \ds{x < a}
> \\
> \ds{-a} & \mbox{if} & \ds{x > a}
> \end{array}\right.
> $$

Because the solution is expresed in terms of the second derivative
$\,\mathrm{f}''\pars{x}$, it's still a solution of $\ds{\,\mathrm{f}\pars{x} + cx + d}$ for some arbitrary constants $\ds{c}$ and $\ds{d}$. It means the 'above checking' becomes
$$
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{-x + cx + d} & \mbox{if} & \ds{x < a}
\\
\ds{-a + cx + d} & \mbox{if} & \ds{x > a}
\end{array}\right.
$$
The original $\ds{\,\mathrm{f}\pars{x}}$ is recovered with
$\color{#f00}{\ds{c = 1}}$ and $\color{#f00}{\ds{d = 0}}$.

> In general, it means there should be additional conditions besides the integral equation.